# Identify special characters into a String that make it uncomparable with another String

Tags: java, string, special-characters, equals

I have a unit test where I compare an expected log file with an actual log file, if they are equals then the test is green.

The problem that I have is that when I perform the following comparison with JUnit:

```
assertEquals(expectedLogFile, reachedLogFile);
```

I get a `junit.framework.ComparisonFailure` as the two strings are not equal.

However, when I open the to see the difference, I see this:

[image]

That clearly looks like some special characters are coming into play, but I'm having a hard time identifying them.

Does anyone have any idea to spot the issue? I'll share below all the tests that I did so far.

**Note:** The two files are pretty large and hard to share here. If you need more input to provide with an answer, let me know and I'll try to see how I can share some more content here on S.O.

---

### How do I build the `reachedLogFile`

In order to collect log lines, I inject a mock implementation of `org.sl4j.Logger` that collects each line called by the logger (`.info(...)`, `.debug(...)`, `.error(...)` etc.) into a synchronized list (because multiple threads write at the same time) and then transforms this content into a `String` like follows:

```
protected String retrieveLogSequence() {
    return LOG_LINES.stream()
            .map(l -> l.getLogLevel() + " - " + l.getMessage())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()))
            .replace(WORKING_DIRECTORY, "AppDir")
            .replace("\n", System.lineSeparator());
}
```

It shouldn't be relevant but `l.getLogLevel()` returns a simple enum `DEBUG, TRACE, INFO, WARN, ERROR` while `l.getMessage()` returns the message that was logged in the production code.

Just to give you an idea of what the content of the list `LOG_LINES` looks like:

[image]

### How do I build the `expectedLogFile`

I have a file in my resources which already contains the expected content.
I read it like this:

```
    File resource = new File("src/test/resources/" + resourceName);
    String expectedLogFile = FileUtils.readFileToString(resource, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return expectedLogFile.replace("(slash)", File.separator);
```

Note: `FileUtils` is an external open-source dependency declared under `commons-io:commons-io:2.6`.

### Where is the difference located?

So I added this sample function just for debugging purposes:

```
private void debugDifference(String reached, String expected) {
    System.out.println("Reached string has " + reached.length() + " characters");
    System.out.println("Expected string has " + expected.length() + " characters");
    long smallerSize = Math.min(reached.length(), expected.length());
    for (int j = 0; j < smallerSize; j++) {
        if (reached.charAt(j) != expected.charAt(j)) {
            System.out.println("Char[" + j + "] is \"" + reached.charAt(j) + "\" for reached and \"" + expected.charAt(j) + "\" for expected");
        }
    }
}
```

The first issue I can see is in the first two lines of the function, where I print the strings length. This is the output:

```
Reached string has 7590 characters
Expected string has 7622 characters
```

Apparently, there are some extra-characters on the "expected" string (meaning on the expected file, which by the way I simply copy-pasted from the debugger `reachedLogFile` so it must definitely be the way of reading it).

But no, it's not that. Instead, it seems there are some "disappearing/negative" characters in the `reachedLogFile` (sorry for the meaningless term but this really goes over my knowledge, please read further to understand what I mean).

Going further in my debug function, I can see that the differences begins around the `150th` character but the console output I get is very weird:

```
" for reached and "
" for expected
Char[150] is "
" for expected
Char[151] is "I" for reached and "
" for expected
Char[152] is "N" for reached and "I" for expected
Char[153] is "F" for reached and "N" for expected
Char[154] is "O" for reached and "F" for expected
Char[155] is " " for reached and "O" for expected
Char[156] is "-" for reached and " " for expected
Char[157] is " " for reached and "-" for expected
Char[158] is "N" for reached and " " for expected
Char[159] is "o" for reached and "N" for expected
Char[160] is " " for reached and "o" for expected
Char[161] is "c" for reached and " " for expected
Char[162] is "o" for reached and "c" for expected
Char[163] is "n" for reached and "o" for expected
Char[164] is "f" for reached and "n" for expected
```

It's like the `149th` character makes disappear the very first part of my `System.out.println()` (the part where I print `"Char[" + j + "] is \"" + reached.charAt(j)`) - it looks like it was some kind of carriage return like `\r\n`, but then why I don't see the first part of my message?.

This repeats few times in the whole comparison, justifying the difference of 11 characters between the two strings (see above when I print `length()` of both strings).
From time to time, there is this "weird" character appearing that breaks even the `System.out.println`.

### Notepad++ in mode "Show all symbols"

Usually, IntelliJ comparator is capable to detect any special character but as shown in the above screenshot, it's not this time.

So when this happens, I usually use Notepad++ in mode "Show all symbols" which for me is like "if it can't, then nobody could".

And here I get another disappointment. From the few print lines that I posted above you can identify the sentence `INFO - No configuration` which is after just 150 characters in the two strings.

But in Notepad++, I don't see any difference at that point between the two files:

[image]

Comment: Backspace character 0x08 (^H)? Difficult to say without seeing the source. Can you not print the char codes of the problematic characters or are you saying they are disappearing? There are all sorts of nasty unprintable control characters

Comment: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php

Comment: @MarsAtomic tried your website but it gives the same result of the Notepad++, the only non-printable characters that it detects are the CR and LF (but clearly there's something more).

Comment: @g00se how can I do that? Do you mean print the char as byte?

Comment: `System.out.printf("0x%02X ",(int)c);` for each `char` 'c'

Comment: @g00se thanks a lot. The first difference met is that the reached file has `0x0D` while the expected file has `0x0A`. It seems it's a matter of \r\n vs. \n, but I really don't see this difference when I check the symbols on the non-printable chars viewers...

Comment: Right. Actually I thought you'd coded for line separator differences

Comment: Hmm. I'm thinking that the tool I linked is on *nix, whereas you appear to be on Windows. Windows is notorious for treating \n as \r\n, so what if you set up a VirtualBox environment with the same versions of Java, JUnit, Hamcrest, whatever and reran your tests there.

Comment: @MarsAtomic my CI is on Linux, I tried to run the test there but except for not seeing anymore the \r (just the \n), there is still no difference and the test still fails.